# Open a VueJS component on a new window

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, window.open

I have a basic VueJS application with only one page.
It's not a SPA, and I do not use vue-router.

I would like to implement a button that when clicked executes the window.open() function with content from one of my Vue Components.

Looking at the documentation from [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) I saw the following statement for URL:

> URL accepts a path or URL to an HTML page, image file, or any other resource which is supported by the browser.

Is it possible to pass a component as an argument for `window.open()`?

Comment: You cannot arbitrarily force some javascript to execute in the window, no. You would need a dedicated page with a dedicated URL for this.

Comment: Short answer is: No. You cannot pass a component into `window.open()`

Answer (score 35):

I was able to use some insights from [an article about Portals in React](https://medium.com/hackernoon/using-a-react-16-portal-to-do-something-cool-2a2d627b0202) to create a Vue component which is able to mount its children in a new window, while preserving reactivity! It's as simple as:

```html
<window-portal>
  I appear in a new window!
</window-portal>
```

Try it in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-r11zy?fontsize=14)!

The code for this component is as follows:

```html
<template>
  <div v-if="open">
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'window-portal',
  props: {
    open: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      windowRef: null,
    }
  },
  watch: {
    open(newOpen) {
      if(newOpen) {
        this.openPortal();
      } else {
        this.closePortal();
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    openPortal() {
      this.windowRef = window.open("", "", "width=600,height=400,left=200,top=200");
      this.windowRef.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.closePortal);
      // magic!
      this.windowRef.document.body.appendChild(this.$el);
    },
    closePortal() {
      if(this.windowRef) {
        this.windowRef.close();
        this.windowRef = null;
        this.$emit('close');
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    if(this.open) {
      this.openPortal();
    }
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    if (this.windowRef) {
      this.closePortal();
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The key is the line `this.windowRef.document.body.appendChild(this.$el)`; this line effectively removes the DOM element associated with the Vue component (the top-level `<div>`) from the parent window and inserts it into the body of the child window. Since this element is the *same reference* as the one Vue would normally update, just in a different place, everything Just Works - Vue continues to update the element in response to databinding changes, despite it being mounted in a new window. I was actually quite surprised at how simple this was!

Comment: This is convenient but sometimes needs to independently, because the parent window will refresh or destroy some component, then some action will be stoped in a new window, do you know how to cut related with a parent window or independently in Vue?

Comment: @HaibaraAi not with this approach - with this component the element in the child window is still managed by the parent window's Vue instance, so if the parent's Vue is destroyed due to a refresh, this element will stop updating. Maybe you could find a way to hook into the hydration process and re-attach that child element to the parent window after a refresh, but I think it would end up being easier to instead load an entirely new window and use typical inter-window communication like `window.postMessage` to implement what you're talking about.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I found vue can config to use multiple pages application, it can refresh independently.

Comment: This is such a good approach but unfortunately not very practical on real scenarios. Too bad because it's truly amazing.

Comment: interesting approach!

Comment: Can you update with unit tests?

Comment: Not sure why @m4heshd says this is not a practical solution. I have just adapted this for a self-printing popup I needed in a Vue app, and it worked wonderfully. The major adaptation I made was to initiate the window contents including a <link> to my stylesheet to allow for the contents to be styled.

Comment: @AmericanUmlaut Trust me. My situation was so complex this couldn't simply work. I even talked about this with the devs on discord. They shot it down immediately.

Comment: @m4heshd Maybe "unfortunately I was not able to apply this to my specific situation" would be a more appropriate comment to make, rather than "unfortunately this isn't practical for real scenarios"? It might not have worked in your scenario but it was a life-saver in mine.

Comment: @AmericanUmlaut Trust me you'll come back to this thread thinking "Now what am I gonna do? ". I wish I could loop you into the conversation with the devs. It was a long time ago. You wouldn't be so thrilled if you were in that conversation. Word of advice, don't make your app heavily rely on this workaround. If this was a "life-saver" for you, it must be some featherweight app.

Comment: For posterity's sake, it's been about two and a half years since we implemented the solution described in this answer, and it has been working great and has caused us no issues since. I have not yet come back to this thread thinking "Now what am I gonna do?" as has been suggested as a likely outcome by some.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot pass a Vue component, because `window.open` doesn't know about Vue. What you can do, however, is to create a route which displays your component and pass this route's URL to `window.open`, giving you a new window with your component. Communication between the components in different windows might get tricky though.

Comment: Thanks for this. it actually makes sense when I come to think about it!

Answer (score 1):

I ported the [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1477697/alex-van-liew) contribution to Composition API and works pretty well.
The only annoyance is that the created window ignores size and position, maybe because it is launched from a Chrome application that is fullscreen. Any idea?

```
<script setup lang="ts">

import {ref, onMounted, onBeforeUnmount, watch, nextTick} from "vue";

const props = defineProps<{modelValue: boolean;}>();
const emit = defineEmits(["update:modelValue"]);

let windowRef: Window | null = null;
const portal = ref(null);

const copyStyles = (sourceDoc: Document, targetDoc: Document): void => {

    // eslint-disable-next-line unicorn/prefer-spread
    for(const styleSheet of Array.from(sourceDoc.styleSheets)) {
        if(styleSheet.cssRules) {
            // for <style> elements
            const nwStyleElement = sourceDoc.createElement("style");

            // eslint-disable-next-line unicorn/prefer-spread
            for(const cssRule of Array.from(styleSheet.cssRules)) {
                // write the text of each rule into the body of the style element
                nwStyleElement.append(sourceDoc.createTextNode(cssRule.cssText));
            }

            targetDoc.head.append(nwStyleElement);
        }
        else if(styleSheet.href) {
            // for <link> elements loading CSS from a URL
            const nwLinkElement = sourceDoc.createElement("link");

            nwLinkElement.rel = "stylesheet";
            nwLinkElement.href = styleSheet.href;
            targetDoc.head.append(nwLinkElement);
        }
    }
};

const openPortal = (): void => {

    nextTick().then((): void => {

        windowRef = window.open("", "", "width=600,height=400,left=200,top=200");
        if(!windowRef || !portal.value) return;
        windowRef.document.body.append(portal.value);
        copyStyles(window.document, windowRef.document);
        windowRef.addEventListener("beforeunload", closePortal);
    })
    .catch((error: Error) => console.error("Cannot instantiate portal", error.message));
};

const closePortal = (): void => {
      if(windowRef) {
        windowRef.close();
        windowRef = null;
        emit("update:modelValue", false);
      }
};

watch(props, () => {
    if(props.modelValue) {
        openPortal();
    }
    else {
        closePortal();
    }
});

onMounted(() => {
    if(props.modelValue) {
      openPortal();
    }
});
onBeforeUnmount(() => {
    if(windowRef) {
      closePortal();
    }
});
</script>

<template>
<div v-if="props.modelValue" ref="portal">
    <slot />
</div>
</template>
```

Comment: The window obeys the size and position of `.open()` if the main Chrome that launches it  is run without `--start-maximized` flag. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

For example, if your main vue is declared like so

```
var app = new Vue({...});
```

If you only need to render a few pieces of data in the new window, you could just reference the data model from the parent window.

```
var app1 = window.opener.app;

var title = app.title;

var h1 = document.createElement("H1");

h1.innerHTML = title;

document.body.appendChild(h1);
```